# "systemd-analyze verify" not only verify my file?

Tags: 19.04, systemd

```
# systemd-analyze verify whatever-not-exist
/lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:4: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
Failed to prepare filename whatever-not-exist: Invalid argument
```

I'm asking systemd-analyze to verify my file, but it always outputs dbus.socket.

How do I fix this so that systemd-analyze verify only outputs errors in my file?